# python pandas - retrieve values from one dataframe with timestamp of another one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a value

```
entry_time=2000-01-03 00:00:00
```

An 2 dataframes.
Lets call the one below "data"

```
timestamp              value                                   
2000-01-03 00:00:00       25  
2000-01-03 00:30:00      -10  
2000-01-03 01:00:00      100  
2000-01-03 01:30:00     -690  
2000-01-03 02:00:00      650  
2000-01-03 02:30:00      320  
2000-01-03 03:00:00      150  
2000-01-03 03:30:00      160
```

and the second one "data2" (below):

```
exit_time              answer  
2000-01-03 01:00:00      true  
2000-01-03 01:30:00      true    
2000-01-03 02:00:00      true    
2000-01-03 02:30:00     false    
2000-01-03 03:00:00      true
```

I want to perform the following operation:
for each row compute the max value between entry_time and exit_time

```
exit_time              answer     max
2000-01-03 01:00:00      true     100
2000-01-03 01:30:00      true     100
2000-01-03 02:00:00      true     650
2000-01-03 02:30:00     false     650
2000-01-03 03:00:00      true     650
```

to do so i need to retrieve the value at each timestamp from data to use it in data2. I tried many variant of such formula but it led me nowhere.

```
data2['value'] = data[data2['exit_time']].value
```

the complete formula of what i am tring to achieve might look something like:

```
data2['max']= data[entry_time: data[data2['exit_time']]].high.max()
```

Thanks!

Comment: you want to `merge`: `data2.merge(data, on='timestamp', how='left')`, this will merge data2 with data on the timestamp column, and add the extra column as desired

Comment: Hi thx - no its not what i want.
I simplified a lot to ask the question in a clear way, but i dont want to just merge the 2 dataframe in the code i am doing. I am performing a more complex operation on the data - hence i need to retrieve it in a way that it similar to what i show in example

Comment: @jimbasquiat EdChum's answer gives the output that you desire. You can then do any operations you want on the "value" column after the merge.

Comment: I edited my question to give a better context. Sorry my question was not clearly put enough for you guys to help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used integers below instead of the datetime data in your original dataframe, but the code is exactly the same.

First, recreate the data:

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'value': [25, -10, 100, -690, 650, 320, 150, 160]})
>>> data
   timestamp  value
0          1     25
1          2    -10
2          3    100
3          4   -690
4          5    650
5          6    320
6          7    150
7          8    160
>>> data2 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'answer': [True, True, True, False, True]})
>>> data2
  answer  timestamp
0   True          3
1   True          4
2   True          5
3  False          6
4   True          7
```

**Then, apply your logic that you want only those rows from `data` whose timestamps are in `data2`. It's as easy as this (your desired result below):**

```
>>> data[data['timestamp'].isin(data2['timestamp'])]
   timestamp  value
2          3    100
3          4   -690
4          5    650
5          6    320
6          7    150
```

Using `data['timestamp'].isin(data2['timestamp'])` with return this:

```
>>> data['timestamp'].isin(data2['timestamp'])
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
Name: timestamp, dtype: bool
```

This gives us boolean values (a mask, effectively): `True` for rows in `data` whose values for `timestamp` are also found in `data2['timestamp']`; False if not found. Then we just use that mask to select the data from, well, `data`.

Edit: The above solution satisfies your original requirements. You've since changed the question, but this gets you much of the way.

Comment: Hi thx, can you look at my edited question? Sorry i'm super noob and i have a hard time to get the timestamp into the slice... you re answer is interesting but i still wouldnt know how to get it to work. Also the logic `data[data['timestamp']]` doesnt work and returns an error.

Comment: `data[data['timestamp'].isin(data2['timestamp'])]` is what you want, although that won't give you your max value calculation you're looking for. Are you looking for a sort of "running" max (i.e. as you move forward in time, keep checking if the current value is greater than the previous max value)?

Comment: yes, basically the slice create a window of multiple rows on which the max is calculated for each row. I tried the formula suggested `data[data['timestamp'].isin(data2['timestamp'])]` but it also didnt work.. Also seems quite ominous for my purpose.. is there no way to retrieve the index of 1 single row to do something with it in a simpler way?